# HTML5 and JavaScript in a desktop application

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am writing an application with HTML5 and Javascript. I want to make it as a desktop application. I wrote a C# application having a browser control (I used the Awesomium). Everything works perfect - I can access the files from the local drive - except that all my Java Script files are available in the client's machine. I would like to package the HTML, JavaScript and the CSS files to something so that the source code is secured. Is this possible? I tried encrypting the JS files, but then the caching became a problem for me. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: HTML does not belong into the Desktop.

Comment: You cannot run code on the client without letting the client see the code.

Comment: You need to rework your program structure. Anything you don't want the client machine having access to, should not be on the client machine. You can obfuscate them or minify them or do this or that, but it really doesn't do anything worthwhile.

Comment: Well, you can try checking out win 8, with win js and html5, you can create desktop apps. But I don't think the approach you are looking for (I suppose a phonegap type) is feasible.